# iOS moving navbar arrow

Tags: ios, user-interface, navigation

Does anyone know how to make this UI component (using Objective-C)?

[image]

The component I am talking about is the small arrow that moves when the user selects a different menu item.
I am not sure what this is called so I am having trouble finding a tutorial for it.  I am also pretty new to core animation so I am not sure how I would begin creating this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626364/draw-triangle-cutout-for-selection-indication-in-uiview) and see if you can reuse the animation code there. It should be straightforward to repurpose what's being done there to suit your needs.

Good Luck!