# ios draw shape under button

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

i want to achieve this functionality..!

[image]

On navigation change the bottom arrow should animate to left or right button selected.

i know only one way i can achieve this functionality by changing the complete background with bottom home selected to videos selected ..

so that i will have four complete background images with homeselected ,videos selected,etc

is their any better way to achieve this..

Comment: helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626364/draw-triangle-cutout-for-selection-indication-in-uiview

Comment: for simple example try this: https://github.com/kferrell/KFSegmentedControlExample

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of custom views at [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com)

Here is [search result](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=segment)

Here is some related

[SDSegmentedControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sdwellsegmentedcontrol)

[image]

One more
[RS3DSegmentedControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rs3dsegmentedcontrol)

Use them according to your need.